# Issue with radio buttons and message boxes in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

In my application for Visual Basic, I have two radio buttons on the third TabPage. I scripted the "No" button to make a message box pop-up if you click it, but when I test it, instead of just showing the message once, it showed the same message again when I selected other option, "Yes".

I tried doing multiple things, but nothing worked. For the radio button, I did a simple line of code like this at first:

```
MsgBox("insert text here", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "insert title here")
```

After I found out it appeared when you changed the selection to Yes, I tried doing this:

```
If RadioButton26_Select() = True Then
   MsgBox("insert text here", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "insert title here")
End If
```

Obviously, that didn't work either. In the first line of code for that radio button, I changed the `RadioButton26_CheckedChanged` to `RadioButton26_Select`:

```
Private Sub RadioButton26_Select(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton26.Select
```

That line I changed didn't have the `()` after the `Select`s, so I put the `()` after after all the `Select`s. That didn't work either.

So, I'm **really** confused here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the [**`RadioButton.Checked` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checked(v=vs.110).aspx). It indicates whether the `RadioButton` is "selected" or not.

You should also do it in the `CheckedChanged` event since that is raised every time the `Checked` value changes.

```
Private Sub RadioButton26_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton26.CheckedChanged
    If RadioButton26.Checked = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("insert text here", "insert title here", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    End If
End Sub
```

As you see I'm using [**`MessageBox.Show()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than the `MsgBox()` function. I recommend you to do so as well since the `MsgBox()` function exists purely for backwards compatibility with VB6, whereas `MessageBox.Show()` is the native .NET-way of doing it.